# Get records between two locations in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

How to get records between two locations in NodeJS with mongoose. I am using function to find records with function like,

```
 getAllEvent: function (locationReq, callback) {    
        Events.find({
        location: {
            $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    loc: locationReq
                },
                $maxDistance: 0,
                $minDistance: 250
            }
        }
    }, {isDeleted: false}, function (error, data) {
        callback((error) ? {} : (data == null) ? {} : data);
    });
    },
```

This function returns null value.

The location for particular record is also stored in collection of database document. in LocationReq two location values will  be sent. I want records if the record is between that two location.

The database document is as below,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59db3a1e56e60915086fb73f"),
    "eventName" : "5643213246",
    "createdId" : "599d698ffa23343efe9c5cbb",
    "eventDateTime" : ISODate("2017-08-09T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "startTime" : ISODate("2017-08-16T13:01:52.379Z"),
    "endTime" : ISODate("2017-08-16T13:01:52.379Z"),
    "location" : {
        "lat" : "59.9500",
        "lng" : "30.3300"
    },
    "description" : "description123",
    "category" : "59db12dab928f105a87348f6",
    "host" : "host",
    "phoneNumber" : 123123,
    "isDisabled" : false,
    "isDeleted" : true,
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-10-09T08:58:06.687Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-10-24T06:47:07.966Z")
}
```

Comment: Define "between". `$near` searches by "nearest"  if that is what you really mean. At any rate your values are "strings", where they need to be numeric.  They really should not be "keys" and would be preferably stored as GeoJSON. And you need a "2dpshere" index here as well if you mean "near". So a few problems and generally more than a little unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What is locationReq, will you please post that ?

Comment: that will be another location field with two lat long

Comment: Will you please post the value of locationReq?

Comment: LocationReq = {[25.9783, 75.6104] , [59.9500, 30.3300]}

Answer (score 0):

```
getAllEvent: function (locationReq, callback) {    
        Events.find({
        loc: {
             $nearSphere: {
                   $geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [lng, lat]},
                   $maxDistance:distance
                          }

    }, {isDeleted: false}, function (error, data) {
        callback((error) ? {} : (data == null) ? {} : data);
    });
    },
```

And replace location parameter to `loc`